# Finding out what file was called immediately before error

Tags: routes, users, debugging

I'm getting the following errors in dblog whenever I look at a page:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in _menu_check_access() (line 635 of /home/mysite/public_html/includes/menu.inc).

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in _menu_check_access() (line 635 of /home/mysite/public_html/includes/menu.inc).

I know it's not Menu that's causing the issue, but rather, some module is passing permissions incorrectly via hook_menu.

I remember reading a long time ago that one way to find out which module is causing core to emit notices, is to drop a function right before the line in question. Alas, I cannot find that page at all.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you able to install XDebug? It makes life awfully easy and only takes about 10 minutes to setup with Eclipse

Comment: That's a thought. Alas, I'm kind of triaging a production instance that somebody else has updated -- I'd have to freshly clone the site to local.

Comment: Bummer :/ What about a different approach - loop through the return from `module_invoke_all('menu')` and check that the `access arguments` for each is a valid, non-empty array. It'll produce some false positives (not all menu items use `user_access()` and not all have arguments) but it should narrow things down a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are tracking down a weird error, editing core is perfectly acceptable.

1. Make sure everything is in your RCS.
2. Edit includes/menu.inc
3. Place a [`print_r(debug_backtrace())`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) near line 635, preferable at the top of [`_menu_check_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/_menu_check_access/7).  Alse `print_r()` the arguments.
4. Trigger the problem.
5. Figure out what happened.
6. Revert the site to the checked in RCS version.

My guess is you are getting weird path, and the argument is wonky for your access check.  In other words, you are trying to access check something that should really 404.

Comment: +1, Instead of printing entire stack, you could also print the last called function . `$trace  = debug_backtrace();array_shift($trace);print_r($trace[0]['function']);`

Comment: I'm getting a lot of output from that and nothing's really sticking out. I'm trying to add some exception handling (Via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520390/stop-script-execution-upon-notice-warning), but I get the unhelpful "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." message. Any thoughts?

Comment: @2-Stroker -- That's helpful; debug_backtrace'ing a Drupal site outputs an obscene amount of text. Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend installing the devel module and using dpm(debug_backtrace()); - It gives much more useful output for data of this scale.

Comment: Apologies for the late accept; this is a rather good answer if unable or unwilling to install debugging tools. Otherwise, Clive's suggestion to clone to local and use Xdebug is a really good idea. Using a proper development methodology is much better than trying to triage a live site!